# Firebase Android Searchview

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I just start learning Firebase and Android. I want to create a search view display data in the listview and filter data from Firebase.(For example Instagram searching section) I have read some documentation and some other questions in SO but I still don't understand how to do it and start it. Can anyone give me some advice? What do I need to do? Where should I start? Should I use Firebaseui? Is there any example I can look at?

Comment: yes u can load your data for particular class in list  and then add filter() function in your adapter.! and call it in search view method.!

Comment: is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

Your code show follow these steps:

1. Retrieve data from the database and store in an array or list.
2. Set a custom list adapter to the list which implement Filterable.
3. Trigger the filter when the users types in the search box

below is an example for retrieving a list of users and setting a filter in the activity:

```
            private List<User> usersList;
            private MyListAdapter adapter;
            private Listview listview;
            private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


               mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

               mDatabase.child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        usersList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot eventSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
                                usersList.add(eventSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            } 

                          adapter = new MyListAdapter(context, usersList);
                          listview = (Listview) findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
                          listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   FilterNow();
                }
            });
        }

private void FilterNow() {
   String text = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText())){
      Toast.makeText(getContext(),"searchbox is empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        friends.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
   }
```

Next you should look up how to make a list adapter implement Filterable.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

create new method "firebaseUserSearch"
the copy your RecyclerView adapter and paste inside. use you databaseReference to filter it.

My FB structure is :

```
 BLABLA:
     Bars:
         01: 
            BarName: "Best bar"
         02:
            BarName: "The Worst bar"
```

And code is here:

```
  ....

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference ("Bars");

  .....


  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String searchText) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchText) {

            searchText = searchView.getQuery().toString();

            firebaseUserSearch (searchText);

            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}



private void firebaseUserSearch (final String searchText) {


    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Bar, ViewHolder>(

            Bar.class,
            R.layout.custom_row,
            ViewHolder.class,
       databaseReference.orderByChild("barName").startAt(searchText.toUpperCase()).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff"))
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Bar model, final int position) {

  ....
```